# Error when trying to send a text input with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I meet problems sending TextInput in a view object with discord.py library. Here is an equivalent of my code leading to the same error:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.content.startswith('!'):
        view = discord.ui.View()
        view.add_item(
            discord.ui.TextInput(label="test")
                     )
        await message.channel.send(view=view)`
```

By running this and sending a message, I get the following error :

> discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035):
> Invalid Form Body In components.0.components.0: Value of field "type"
> must be one of (2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8).

I start to believe it is an error from the discord.py library, anyone see something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot add `TextInput` to the view. What you could do with `TextInput` is add it to a modal. And you can trigger this modal by clicking a button in the view. This can be a common solution. 
The error code `Invalid Form Body In components.0.components.0: Value of field "type" must be one of (2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8).` means the same, and type

- 2 means Button
- 3,5,6,7,8 related to SelectMenu

  - 3 means select
  - 5 means user_select
  - 6 means role_select
  - 7 means mentionable_select
  - 8 means channel_select

    (These things above can be added to the `ui.View`)
- 4 means TextInput (which cannot be added to the view)